# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/lib/ReactPerf' in '\node_modules\react-addons-perf'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and ReactDOM of version 16.0.0 and react-addons-perf 15.4.2 that is latest version. But i am gating this compile time error.

./node_modules/react-addons-perf/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/lib/ReactPerf' in '....\node_modules\react-addons-perf'

Comment: read the breaking changes on react v16

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To follow up on what Rei Dien said, the [React 16 announcement](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html) mentions the following:

> **react-addons-perf** no longer works at all in React 16. It’s likely that
>   we’ll release a new version of this tool in the future. In the
>   meantime, you can [use your browser’s performance tools to profile
>   React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab).

To put it simply, just `npm uninstall react-addons-perf` and everything should be fine.

Comment: 223seneca, you are right react v16 doesn't support react-addons-perf but currently i am learning about react performance. So I have changed version or react and react-dom to 15.6.2 and it is working fine.